# Accessing Sql Server database using new loginname

Tags: sql-server

I created a database in my local sql server express using my windows account. Recently my window's login name has changed and I can no longer access my database which was created using my old window's login name.

any suggestion on what do I need to do to access my database using new username ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Log on as a SQL Server administrator, and run:

```
ALTER LOGIN YourSqlServerLogin WITH NAME = YourNewName
```

SQL Server will verify that the accounts match, [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx):

> NAME = login_name The new name of the login that is being renamed. If
>   this is a Windows login, the SID of the Windows principal
>   corresponding to the new name must match the SID associated with the
>   login in SQL Server. The new name of a SQL Server login cannot contain
>   a backslash character ().

Comment: thanks for your response. however, I don't want to alter the login name. My problem is that database was created using old window's username, with new window's username I can't access the database

Comment: As far as I know the Windows username has to match the SQL Server login name.  You'll have to change one or the other.